# icCube partitioning for flat file data sources

Tags: iccube

On the documentation for partitioning: http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/user_guide/reference/partitioning_edition.php

It says that partitioning is only supported for DB tables.  Is it possible to have partitioning for flat file data sources?

thanks,
John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flat files do not support table partitionning (see edition below).

Note that table partitioning allows for:

1) faster read as several partitions can be read at the same time
2) internal cube data being partitioned

With flat files 1) does not make much sense and 2) can be achieved with "level" partitioning I guess.

You can contact [icCube](http://www.icCube.com/contact) for more details and/or to request this feature.

EDITION: This feature will be supported in upcoming version of icCube.

Comment: But it also allows to re-load or delete individual partitions. Without this I can probably incrementally load data into a cube but would have to reprocess everything if some data needed to be removed. Is that correct?

Thanks